# Getting specidic values from PHP arrays

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the first value from array, then the first value key + 3 ; then +6 then + 9  ans so on

Take this array for example,

```
array(1,2,5,14,19,2,11,3,141,199,52,24,16)
```

i want extract a value every 3 so the result would be

```
array(1,14,11,199,16)
```

Can i do that with existing PHP array function?

Comment: is this a task for school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is function that will handle extracting the values from a given array. You can specify the number of steps between each value and if the results should use the same keys as the original. This should work with regular and associative arrays.

```
<?php

function extractValues($array, $stepBy, $preserveKeys = false)
{
  $results = array();

  $index = 0;

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if ($index++ % $stepBy === 0) {
          $results[$key] = $value;
      }
  }

  return $preserveKeys ? $results  : array_values($results);
}

$array = array(1, 2, 5, 14, 19, 2, 11, 3, 141, 199, 52, 24, 16);
$assocArray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 5, 'd' => 14, 'e' => 19, 'f' => 2, 11, 3, 141, 199, 52, 24, 16);

print_r(extractValues($array, 3));

print_r(extractValues($array, 3, true));

print_r(extractValues($assocArray, 5));

print_r(extractValues($assocArray, 5, true));
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 14
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 199
    [4] => 16
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [3] => 14
    [6] => 11
    [9] => 199
    [12] => 16
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 52
)
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [f] => 2
    [4] => 52
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop and increment the counter variable by 3.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count(your array); $i+3) {
echo $myarray[i]
}
```

Comment: since OP wants the first element, its best to start your loop with $i=0 instead of $i=1

Comment: Thanks, I didnt notice that when I copy pasted the code, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one:

```
 <?php 
    $your_array = array (1,2,5,14,19,2,11,3,141,199,52,24,16);
    $every_3 = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($your_value as $value) {
        $i++;
        if($i%3==0){
            $every_3[]=$value;
        }
    }
    var_dump($every_3);
    ?>
```

Comment: Why you don't just use the index of the foreach instead of manually managing that counter. It is a bit overhead this way

Comment: in case of associative array that index helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop and check the key.

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if ($key % 3 === 0) {
      $result[] = $value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$arr=array (1,2,5,14,19,2,11,3,141,199,52,24,16);
$narr=array();  
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i=$i+3){
$narr[]=$arr[$i]
}
print_r($narr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$mynums = array(1,2,5,14,19,2,11,3,141,199,52,24,16);
foreach ($mynums as $key => $value) {

    if ( $key % 3 === 0)
    {
        $newnum[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($newnum);

?>
```

Comment: Why are you manually adding the first entry? This way you will add it twice

Comment: @Dirkos oops my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(1,2,5,14,19,2,11,3,141,199,52,24,16);
$matches = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    if($key%3 === 0)
    {
        $matches[] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do it would be to use a loop, count the length of an array, and loop through using a % mathmatical operator.

It gives you a remainder of a division: https://www.php.net/operators.arithmetic